# How do I re-light a torch?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I've been hoarding torches, because...well, I wouldn't like to be stuck in the Grimrock dungeons without any light! When one is about to go out I can often just swap it out for a new one and have a nice steady light again.

However, if there's a way to re-light torches (maybe by interacting with torches already on the wall?) then I can dump a few and just keep enough to appease my inner scaredy-cat. Is this possible? Or are torches 'depleted' once they go out?

I should point out that I've only just started playing (still on level 1) so if there's a relevant but non-obvious game mechanic I'm missing here, please let me know.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Once a torch is fully depleted, you cannot use it for light anymore . However, a torch that is almost-but-not-quite burned out (which gives off a dimmer, orange light) can be placed in a wall sconce where it will burn at full brightness forever. Putting it in and taking it out will not refresh it back up to full strength, however.

One alternative to carrying around a bunch of torches is to get your mage a few points in Spellcraft and cast the Light spell. It had a fairly long duration and is cheap to cast. You'll still want to carry 3-4 torches in your inventory, though, as some are needed for puzzles.

You can cast Light by:

> Getting Spellcraft to 5 and casting via the Balance & Light runes. If the rune grid were a numeric keypad, those runes would correspond to the 8 and 5 positions.

Comment: A clarification: depleted torches, which glow with a more orange light, can be placed in wall sconces and will glow with full brightness. However, completely burned out torches (which have a different inventory icon) will no longer provide light even in sconces.